# Disable Screen Recording Only in Android

Tags: android, react-native

I want to restrict user to not record the screen, to I setted a FLAG_SECURE flag. Because of that I'm able to restrict user to record mobile screen, but the problem with that it is also restircting user to take screen shots. What I can do it for to restrict only recording of screen, not screen-shots.

Flag

`getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);`

Comment: just look at *screen recording* as continuously taking a screenshot of the app, 25 times per second. So you basically want to prevent taking 25 screenshots/sec, but to allow let's say 1 screenshot/sec?

Comment: There is no direct broadcast which refers to a screenshot request. So you might be interested in providing a button in your app which allows a user to take a screenshot by clicking that button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately your only option is `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE`.
There is no way to detect video recording on Android to prevent it only.